# C++ priority of compare operator overload vs conversion operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    int k;

    operator int() {
        cout << "convert int" << endl;
        return k;
    }

#if USE_COMPARE
    bool operator < (int rhs) {
        cout << "compare with" << endl;
        return (k < rhs);
    }
#endif
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.k = 3;
    int m = 5;


    if (f < m) {
        cout << 1 << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << 0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When `USE_COMPARE` is defined, the comparison of `if (f<m)` will use the compare operator overload.  If `USE_COMPARE` is not defined, it will convert `f` from `Foo` to `int`, and then do the integer compare.  It seems to me that the compare operator overload is in higher priority than the conversion operator.  Could any one confirm this in the C++ standard point of view?

Yet I think it's nature that the compare operator should take priority. But please answer the question in the perspective of C++ standard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

13.3.3.2/2

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as
>   defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion
>   sequence than a user-defined con- version sequence or an ellipsis
>   conversion sequence, and
>
> a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion
>   sequence than an ellipsis conver- sion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

13.3.3.1/3

> A well-formed implicit conversion sequence is one of the following
>   forms: — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1),
>
> — a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2), or
>
> — an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

13.3.3.1/8

> If no conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter
>   type, the implicit conversion sequence is the standard conversion
>   sequence consisting of the identity conversion (13.3.3.1.1).

13.3.3.1.2/1

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard
>   conversion sequence followed by a user- defined conversion (12.3)
>   followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined
>   conversion is specified by a conversion function (12.3.2), the initial
>   standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit
>   object parameter of the conversion function.

There are two variants for compiler, if compare operator is defined:

1) Let

```
IF = Identity(f)
```

Call:

```
IF.operator <(int)
```

2) Let:

```
IF = Identity(f);
converted_int = Identity(IF.operator int());
```

Call:

```
operator < (converted_int, int);
```

Implicit-conversion sequence is better than user-conversion sequence.
There are two many words in standard about overload resolution for quotes, if you want you can read par 13.3, or just 13.3.3[over.best.ics].

Comment: But it seems to me that I EXPLICITLY defined the `<` operator overload, and thus the  `<` operator overload should be used since it requires no conversion, right?

Comment: @Robin Hsu, This is written in answer actually.

Comment: You seems to say that two variances exist, meaning that both are legal and some compiler do this and others do that?  Or could you explain more and forgive me poor English...(Or poor C++ :-))

Comment: @RobinHsu Compiler have actually two variants. But by standard first (only identity conversion) should be chosen.

Comment: You mean, by standard, there should only be only one choice, but in practical, some compilers choose not to follow the standard, right?

Comment: @RobinHsu no, i mean, that overloaded operator should be chosen anyway by standard.

Comment: So what are the "two variants" means?  Perhaps "variants" are a special term in compiler technology, right? Are "variants" just the considerations for the compiler and after evaluating the priority, the compile will only take the one with higher priority, right?   I just mistakenly think the variants means variations that compiler can choose...

Comment: @RobinHsu read standard please. There are two candidates, one is overloaded operator < and second is builtin operator <. First will be chosen to be best viable function, due overloaded resolution.